# Drop movie with 'unknown' category

Tags: python, pandas

How do I drop the movie assigned with 'unknown' category from dataframe?

```
    movie id    movie title release date    unknown Action  Adventure   Animation   Childrens   Comedy  Crime   ... Fantasy Film-Noir   Horror  Musical Mystery Romance Sci-Fi  Thriller    War Western
0   1   Toy Story   01-Jan-1995 0   0   0   1   1   1   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   2   GoldenEye   01-Jan-1995 0   1   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
2   3   Four Rooms  01-Jan-1995 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
3   4   Get Shorty  01-Jan-1995 0   1   0   0   0   1   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   5   Copycat 01-Jan-1995 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
5 rows × 22 columns
``
```

Comment: try `df = df.drop('unknown', axis=1)`

Comment: I am looking to drop the movie where the genre is unknow. Not just drop the column unknown. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
df = df[df['unknown']!=1]
```

Or this:

```
df = df[~(df['unknown']==1)]
```